# How to synchronize Gnote?

Tags: ubuntu, sync

How can I synchronize Gnote on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your home folder and find the '.gnote' folder
Drag and drop this into Ubuntu One
Right-click on the .gnote folder and select 'Make link'
Drag the link it makes back to your home folder and rename it '.gnote'.